# Cual es el error en este codigo MySQL-PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy intentando extraer el valor de una forma Para que este sea sumado a un valor de una fila en una tabla en mysql, mediante un string que extrae el valor de una consulta y este valor es usado para actualizar la informacion del registro, pero no lo hace. Cual podria ser el error?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$SQL="select Cantidad + ".$_POST['Cantidad']." from gasolina where Gasolina = \"".$_POST['Gasolina']."\"";
                 $resultado = mysql_query($SQL, $idconexion); 
                 $fila = mysql_fetch_row($resultado);
                 $SQL="UPDATE gasolina SET Cantidad=\"".$fila[0]."\" WHERE where Gasolina = \"".$_POST['Gasolina']."\"";
                }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que te referis con que no lo hace? en realidad tu update no hace nada, porque estas seteando los mismos valores que trajiste en el select. vos que querias hacer?

Comment: Bueno, el truco esta en que a el valor de la bdd se le suma el valor de la forma `".$_POST['Cantidad']."`, asi que basicamente el resultado de esa consulta es el valor que necesito hacer update en el registro, asi que eso hago, mas sin embargo no e actualiza la informacion.

Comment: eso es totalmente innecesario.. tu update puede ser cantidad=cantidad+(loquequeressumar)... mas alla de eso, probablemente en cantidad no estas recibiendo nada.. y por eso no funciona

Comment: Cimo puntualizacion para este tipo de datos es recomendable usar el tipo DECIMAL o NUMERIC. **Los tipos DECIMAL y NUMERIC se usan para guardar valores para los que es importante preservar una precisión exacta, por ejemplo con datos monetarios.**

Answer (score 0):

Parece que hay un error en la consulta, has escrito dos veces la cláusula `where`:

```
$SQL="select Cantidad + ".$_POST['Cantidad']." from gasolina where Gasolina = \"".$_POST['Gasolina']."\"";
$resultado = mysql_query($SQL, $idconexion); 
$fila = mysql_fetch_row($resultado);
$SQL="UPDATE gasolina SET Cantidad=\"".$fila[0]."\" WHERE where Gasolina = 
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
\"".$_POST['Gasolina']."\"";
```

Pruebas con esta:

```
 $SQL="UPDATE gasolina SET Cantidad=\"".$fila[0]."\" WHERE Gasolina =\"".$_POST['Gasolina']."\"";
```

**NOTA**

Esta respuesta intenta ayudar a descubrir cuál es es la posible causa a que tu consulta no funcione, desconozco si lo haces de este modo por algún tipo de restricción o exigencia particular, si no fuera así, te sugiero que hagas caso a la recomendación que te hace gbianchi en su comentario y explores esa posbilidad.

Comment: Bueno, despues de algo de debugging, encontre que el problema esta en que no se ejecuta el update; Ya he puesto en mysql la linea de update y se ejecuta correctamente, mas el php no ejecuta esta linea, por que sera?

Comment: Podrías ir depurando y actualizando la pregunta con los resultados para poder encontrar el fallo.